# Tabla de Hash funciones en c++

Tags: c++, array, hash

Estoy aprendiendo a implementar Tablas de Hash en c++, creé mi Tabla según el trabajo que se me asigno el cual primero era crear una matriz que genere números aleatorios y a partir de ella crear una tabla de Hash, lo cual hice pero luego de esto me pide que le de funciones de de buscar un elemento en la tabla de Hash o eliminar o modificar un elemento, no se cómo aplicar estas funciones y he buscado información pero no encuentro información sobre estas funciones. Acá esta mi código:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int      op, res, p;
    int      n = 47;          // number of elements generated
    int      n1 = 81;         // The size of the hash table
    long int mas[47];         // Array of generated elements
    int      hash[100] = {0}; // hash table
    int      adress;          // Hash address
    int      i0 = 1;          // Sample number
    int      k1 = 0;          // Table fill factor = n / n1
    int      k2 = 0;          // Total number of samples
    int      flag = 0;
    int      tmp = 0;
    int      k = 0;
    system("cls");
    srand(time(NULL));
    while (k < n) {
        flag = 0;
        tmp = (100 * (1 + rand() % 9)) + (rand() % 100);
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            if (mas[i] == tmp) {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0) {
            mas[k] = tmp;
            ++k;
        }
    }

    cout << "GENERATION OF RANDOM NUMBERS: " << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        cout << setw(2) << i << setw(7) << mas[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "TABLA DE HASHT : " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        adress = (mas[i] * mas[i]) % n1;
        k2++;
        int adress0 = adress;
        if (hash[adress] == 0) {
            hash[adress] = mas[i];
            k1++;
        } else {
            while (hash[adress] != 0) {
                adress = (adress0 + i0 * i0) % n1;
                i0++;
                k2++;
            }
            hash[adress] = mas[i];
        }
        i0 = 1;
    }

    for (int ht = 0; ht < n1; ht++)
        cout << setw(2) << ht << setw(7) << hash[ht] << " ";

    cout << "\n\nTable fill : " << double(n) / double(n1) << endl;

    cout << "Number of samples :" << double(k2) / double(n) << endl;
    cout << endl;
    std::cout << "MENU";
    std::cout << "\nSelect the operation to perform:\n";
    std::cout << "\n1.Search for an item  \t 2.add an element";
    std::cout << "\n3.modify an element \t 4.remove an item";
    std::cout << "\n5.get out";
    std::cout << "\n\nEnter an option";
    scanf("%d", &op);

    switch (op) {
    case 1:
        system("cls");
        puts("1. Search for an item ");

        gets("primary key");
        puts("2. to return");
        gets("to return");

        p = adress;
        printf("\n\nthe key is successful");
        (adress);
        break;
    case 2:
        system("cls");
        puts("1. add an element");
        gets("primary key");
        puts("2. to return");
        gets("to return");

        p = adress;
        printf("\n\nthe key is successful");
        (adress);
        break;
    case 3:
        system("cls");
        puts("1. modify an element");
        gets("primary key");
        puts("2. to return");
        gets("to return");

        p = adress;
        printf("\n\nthe key is successful");
        (adress);
        break;
    case 4:
        system("cls");
        puts("1. remove an item");
        gets("primary key");
        puts("2. to return");
        gets("to return");

        p = adress;
        printf("\n\nthe key is successful");
        (adress);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He leído tres veces tu pregunta y no entiendo qué estás preguntando. ¿A qué te refieres con "aplicar funciones"?

Comment: Me refiero, a agregar funciones tales como buscar un objeto en la tabla borrarlo,editarlo etc

Comment: Entonces ¿Cuál es la pregunta? A) No sabes implementar funciones de búsqueda y quieres que alguien las implemente B) Sabes implementar funciones de búsqueda pero no sabes cómo integrarlas en tu código.

Comment: se como implementarlas mas no se como integrarlas a mi codigo